# Modular clothing for RPG

Tags: modeling, mesh

What would be the best way to create multiple articles of clothing/armor to be compatible with multiple different character models of varying shape and size?

For example, if I have a character mesh and I extrude his stomach out a bit more and save that as a separate mesh then design an armor piece for the first mesh, would there be a way to have that armor piece recognize the changes between the two meshes and adjust accordingly?

Comment: "*What would be the best way...*" This would be an opinion based question, the rest seems both far too broad and not very blender related. Is this for some sort of game engine? What have you tried so far, could you show some screenshots

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I'm not sure how to go about this in an efficient manor. The best way would be subjective and hard to define but I'm mainly taking in factors like ease of use and scalability. The idea is that I'd have multiple player models and armors/accessories, all interchangeable with automatic shape fitting. Some may have larger arms, broader shoulder, bigger heads ect... I was thinking that I could define key points on the player models like the neck and head for example and calculate a delta transformation between models which is then applied to the armor/accessories.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to blender so I'm not sure how I'd go about doing this delta transformation idea. My general concept is to group all the vertices into manageable segments where I would apply articles of clothing (head, torso, legs). These vertices will be consistent throughout my character models since I'll pretty much copy them and move them around slightly. I would then store the tranformations to each vertice compared to the base, design the clothing around one character model, and apply said transformations to the clothing. Is there a way to do what I described?

Comment: Maybe look into shapekeys